# How to calculate how clickable a button or object is on screen

Tags: controls

Given a screen of dimensions AxB, and a button or other UI element of size CxD, what are the best methods of calculating a rough gauge of how easy it is to click/reach/target that interface element?

Comment: Quick comment: - screen resolution is not a good measure these days - use physical dimensions, and consider the type of device and the way it's held.

Comment: I'm guessing [Fitts's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts's_law) and the Shannon formulation is appropriate here?

Comment: Sounds like you're basically asking for Fitts' Law, or are you asking about something more specific? What's your definition of "clickable"? Error rate, time to click?

Comment: Well I had the idea of colour coding elements on a screen based on how easy they were to hit as a vague rough guide, but for that I would need a rough metric, so something like Fitts law could work yes

Comment: There are a few cases where Fitts' Law doesn't quite fit (sorry I couldn't help myself). A very small target (e.x. 10px by 10px) might be hard to easily hit anywhere in the middle of a screen. If you take that same target and place it at the edge or corner of a window, the target immediately becomes infinitely wide/tall as the cursor is unable to overshoot the target due to the boundaries stopping it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Roger pointed out in a comment, it looks like it is Fitt's Law your going for. It is possible to try it in this [web based test](http://www.tele-actor.net/fitts/). At the end you get the result and the way it's been calculated. [Try it out](http://www.tele-actor.net/fitts/):

[image: Fitt's Law web based test and calculations]

You make 50 hits of different distance and width looking like this when in test:

[image: Fitt's Law in test]